# how to load data from a database to a radio button

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have two radio buttons for NEW and OLD student.
Whenever i click the datagridview in my form, i want to load it also to a radio button.
Here is my code.

```
   Private Sub dg1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dg1.CellContentClick
    Try
        txtProductName.Text = dg1.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value
        dtpImport.Text = dg1.Item(2, e.RowIndex).Value
        dtpExs.Text = dg1.Item(3, e.RowIndex).Value
        txtQuantity.Text = dg1.Item(4, e.RowIndex).Value
        txtPrice.Text = dg1.Item(5, e.RowIndex).Value
        txtUnitPrice.Text = dg1.Item(6, e.RowIndex).Value
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(changephoto(CInt(dg1.SelectedCells(0).Value)))
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        rbtNew.Text = dg1.Item(8, e.RowIndex).Selected
        rbtOld.Text = dg1.Item(8, e.RowIndex).Selected
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


End Sub
```

This is my code for radio button but it gives me wrong result.

```
rbtNew.Text = dg1.Item(8, e.RowIndex).Selected
rbtOld.Text = dg1.Item(8, e.RowIndex).Selected
```

[My screenshot of my forms with wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2YE5.jpg)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yewby.jpg)

Comment: In what sense does it give the wrong result?  Have a look here on what to include when asking questions. [ask] ... Cheers

Comment: i add the screenshot for much clearer explanation of what the problem is.

Comment: What is the type of column where information about "New" or "Old" are saved?

Comment: @Fabio  Varchar(50) - sqlserver2008 is my database server.

Comment: `Selected` property has `Boolean` type. Use `Value` property instead.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , i use the Value property , but there's a little problem.. i have posted image2 above for clearer explanation of what happened to the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because value which represent "new" or "old" student is String(Varchar),
then you need to convert this value to the boolean for `RadioButton`

```
const OLDSTUDENT As String = "Old"
const NEWSTUDENT As String = "New"

Me.rbtNew.Text = NEWSTUDENT
Me.rbtOld.Text = OLDSTUDENT

Me.rbtNew.Checked = NEWSTUDENT.Equals(dg1.Item(8, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
Me.rbtOld.Checked = OLDSTUDENT.Equals(dg1.Item(8, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
```